# Asking for help making my Magic Eightball project scalable to smaller screens

Tags: css, sass

[Project on CodePen](https://codepen.io/stellarwobble/pen/porWLmE)

I understand that I could make the `height` and `width` of `.ball` and `.aperture` percentages to deal with the resizing of the screen. However, what I'm stuck on is sizing .triangle so that the shape maintains its integrity.

```
.triangle{
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 75px solid transparent;
  border-right: 75px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 125px solid rgb(147, 98, 238);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler to create the triangle using clip-path with percentages.

```css
.triangle {
  width: 20vmin;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background-color: rgb(147, 98, 238);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. Do you have any suggestions on how to center text with in the with div with clip-path applied?

Comment: This is I think a more complex, and different , question if the text is more than one line